# Recreate UITableViewCell from storyboard for each row without dequeuing

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8, storyboard

Here's an interesting problem I'm trying to solve.

I want to use a single cell that is configured in storyboard for different cell configurations by removing stuff I don't need from the cell.

Here's how to cell is constrained.
[image: Storyboard cell]

Basically, if I don't need image for the step (or the red view) I just remove it from cell, and everything aligns dynamically just perfect, and I do not have to calculate cell height or do any coding. However, since I have to reuse the cells, when I get the cell for the next row I do not have that view. I can add it again to cell, but I loses all of the constraints.

In case you need it for ideas, here's some code:

```
class RecipeStepTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var preparationLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var stepNumberLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var stepImageView: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var stepTextLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var stepTimerView: UIView!

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
  }
}
```

And this is how I handle it it `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RecipeStepCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as RecipeStepTableViewCell
let step = stepForIndexPath(indexPath)

if step.image == nil {
    cell.stepImageView.removeFromSuperview()
}
// etc.
```

I really like this approach since I don't have to build 10 cell configurations, and all I need is to force it to create a new cell for each row.

By the way, the view will only have 5, 6 cells so performance shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like removing the image is deleting all the constraints associated with it.

I have an idea. Instead of removing the image, you can just adjust constraints when step.image == nil, since the image will be invisible anyway.

This would be done by using storyboard to connect IBOutlets to the constraints. It would look like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var constraintToTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

And then later to adjust it,

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RecipeStepCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as RecipeStepTableViewCell
let step = stepForIndexPath(indexPath)

if step.image == nil { //Set constraint(s) so imageView takes up no space
    cell.constraintToTop.constant = 0
}
else { //Go back to original constraints
    cell.constraintToTop.constant = 50
}
```

This may require creating many IBOutlets for your constraints to get the desired result, but this is the general idea.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: This works just great. The only problem is that I also have to save spacing constraints and set them to zero as well, but it works with reuse identifier like tables are supposed to. Thanks!